# IIS 8, SERVER SSL the UserTrust Network Certification path not found

Tags: ssl, iis-8

Please help me explain on the marchine, ssl of my website has not the UserTrust Network Certification path.

See all images below

[ssl wrong has not found the UserTrust Network Certification path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct4gJ.png)

[ssl correct with the UserTrust Network Certification path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2hHg.png)

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found the answser for my question is

Using MMC/Certificates and delete all COMODO RSA... that I miss import not correct

After then I re import SSL of website

Yes, I see correct and you can use tool as "https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname" to check